# pgfplots - Problem with the fill command

Tags: pgfplots, fill

I am trying to plot 2 different images one on top of each other using the fill option of `\addplot`. I import the data from a `.csv` file and the values look correct to me. However, when I compile it, it looks like a line is splitting the graph and the color is reversed. 
[image]

My code is as follows:

```
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, fit}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Dark2}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,calc,positioning,fit}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={font={\scriptsize}}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.03)},anchor=south}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
font={\scriptsize}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlarge x limits=-1,
    height=4cm,
    width=\textwidth,
    axis y line=left,
    axis line style=-,
    y axis line style=-,
    %ymin=-30,
    ytick scale label code/.code={}, 
    xtick={1, 96, 192, 288, 384, 480, 576},
    xticklabels={30/07, 31/07, 01/08, 02/08, 03/08, 04/08, 05/08},
    grid=major,
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize},  
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
    label style={font=\scriptsize},
    title style={font=\scriptsize},
    xlabel={Time [days]},
    ylabel={Power [kW]},
    legend columns = 2,
    legend style={draw=none, fill=none}
    ]
\addplot[color=red, fill=red, mark=,] table[col sep=semicolon,trim cells=true, y=chp_OC]{data/Collective_El_productionOC_weekB.csv};
\addlegendentry{CHP\textsubscript{OC}}
\addplot[color=blue, fill=blue, mark=,] table[col sep=semicolon,trim cells=true, y=pv_OC] {data/Collective_El_productionOC_weekB.csv};
\addlegendentry{PV\textsubscript{OC}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Electricity demand and production of the BC and OC for the collective variant.}
\label{fig:ElUsage&Production_Collective_weekB}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My `.csv` file is this one:

```
time;pv_OC;chp_OC
1;0;-49.9375780274656
2;0;-50.125313283208
3;0;-46.2439840970914
4;0;-49.7794580970384
5;0;-46.5067340067339
6;0;-46.8948035487959
7;0;-46.225614927905
8;0;-46.9513490545995
9;0;-46.2785242055875
10;0;-46.7948717948717
11;0;-46.5465465465465
12;0;-46.6365785514721
13;0;-46.6019417475728
14;0;-47.0002165908598
15;0;-46.6579861111111
16;0;-46.8409586056645
17;0;-47.1512770137524
18;0;-46.4606618452772
19;0;-46.8646864686468
20;0;-46.2962962962962
21;0;-47.0952065385464
22;0;-46.3036741921204
23;0;-47.0791749833666
24;0;-48.3422222222222
25;0;-62.7859027511657
26;0;-63.611722427618
27;0;-65.6798669522272
28;0;-68.0193409382615
29;0;-67.0808913205049
30;0;-66.6106912958298
31;0;-68.9392699397597
32;0;-67.4574598720509
33;0;-67.1382084931924
34;0;-67.8302990268473
35;0;-66.0903496897913
36;-2.71590685608506;-65.3336295351873
37;-3.79703684940074;-64.865986136994
38;-5.28672068626196;-64.5213817026272
39;-1.70237537455756;-63.5393914679336
40;-2.04193673564172;-64.0991099326863
41;-2.38004039653586;-63.6837914181594
42;-2.87625222858342;-66.2575500265188
43;-3.55454148842418;-63.3824992164266
44;-4.18233204793322;-64.3454076712951
45;-25.7734456916835;-63.983443508754
46;-25.7205304010562;-64.3627482574194
47;-26.0096634019761;-64.016381264407
48;-26.5326378752355;-64.5657973117992
49;-27.360287780553;-64.412976641348
50;-26.3914810350649;-64.308886318523
51;-25.6296651493313;-63.9586671820771
52;-25.0190324486409;-64.2874809739817
53;-24.5565681443596;-64.1104590713137
54;-22.6458401208827;-64.3576729551684
55;-20.8597646707947;-67.4514940894973
56;-19.1998410166367;-64.0656088423047
57;-17.6637443933161;-64.4337809533695
58;-14.7463755604187;-66.1753854631519
59;-12.0084985281059;-64.9602478798299
60;-6.59879523806312;-66.058317564334
61;-5.61996859259129;-64.8696469480356
62;-4.57763057318654;-64.6661458055397
63;-3.44886074028423;-65.4917538351718
64;-2.25712628616039;-66.7341998419401
65;-1.03972062783541;-65.5807133652427
66;-0.784535044222811;-65.5261937724209
67;-0.522484271876818;-69.8938451398831
68;-0.260973829418343;-73.9528344813775
69;0;-73.869690014907
70;0;-69.5412315970652
71;0;-75.0655716145132
72;0;-74.2899359938404
73;0;-70.1760029723034
74;0;-71.4616467489099
75;0;-78.3275999727904
76;0;-74.0283698229795
77;0;-73.7118631825275
78;0;-75.0446642625661
79;0;-74.2683458254743
80;0;-72.9967012511693
81;0;-71.2238962388054
82;0;-75.8969278583814
83;0;-69.2650376742038
84;0;-74.8512123446227
85;0;-74.7487116096687
86;0;-72.4386843519697
87;0;-69.5015036370678
88;0;-69.479852820651
89;0;-69.3436037668317
90;0;-68.4198240829765
91;0;-66.7498316844172
92;0;-69.2409808279105
93;0;-64.8378048695262
94;0;-65.7277569092904
95;0;-66.0076038147259
96;0;-66.1039396903495
97;0;-15.7480314960629
98;0;-14.68332237563
99;0;-12.272627657243
100;0;-12.0772946859903
101;0;-12.5164690382081
102;0;-11.6381203337725
103;0;-12.3212321232123
104;0;-12.101210121012
105;0;-12.1252204585537
106;0;-11.68430335097
107;0;-12.3456790123456
108;0;-11.9284294234592
109;0;-12.5911199469847
110;0;-11.9521912350597
111;0;-12.173528109783
112;0;-12.6162018592297
113;0;-11.7542692392991
114;0;-12.4196052339764
115;0;-11.7777777777777
116;0;-12.3484559643975
117;0;-11.7539761984218
118;0;-18.1299076854611
119;0;-31.47044341638
120;0;-60.3705813922335
121;0;-71.4
122;0;-72.475
123;0;-72.4516757057432
124;0;-75.4217203401645
125;0;-79.28531546622
126;0;-75.6114605171208
127;0;-76.0635451552552
128;0;-78.8846854420624
129;0;-75.6172839506172
130;0;-74.662171653322
131;0;-72.7581699346405
132;-2.63406580739042;-72.3049518833397
133;-3.68043935472862;-72.181142589609
134;-4.86439050083897;-71.6548265064648
135;-2.00691730151581;-72.3079018303484
136;-2.85530325063678;-71.5360346149124
137;-3.61472789993327;-72.2054451995113
138;-4.12499783780555;-71.7255604257099
139;-4.49521762380721;-74.1661036997565
140;-4.71494138539586;-71.75668879071
141;-25.8097052778508;-72.7941740178438
142;-28.2809851442178;-72.0596287785759
143;-30.6153465283307;-73.0397582113041
144;-32.7893746813086;-74.3746720952724
145;-34.7577735891439;-72.9588972747634
146;-35.1199889937848;-72.3450312949692
147;-35.640128003279;-73.2109829039323
148;-36.2399809697545;-72.5420008392978
149;-36.9500860496466;-72.7058409361654
150;-34.4717331139373;-73.1447095754145
151;-32.036200764031;-72.3281568964105
152;-29.3907563948426;-72.5112948532776
153;-26.6108365340138;-72.1498202037793
154;-22.4681168329195;-73.4142111814842
155;-18.2181352833555;-74.3569121540003
156;-6.90561470302878;-72.8753271891778
157;-6.31430393406497;-73.1535456277733
158;-5.3360614917658;-75.5241577475286
159;-4.10516016049089;-76.2184923101487
160;-2.69302294331933;-80.6736428839343
161;-1.18766462461018;-74.1489384211167
162;-0.89679114035112;-74.6629416191253
163;-0.597182377295449;-77.3231529543964
164;-0.298275289459767;-77.3580607930563
165;0;-78.1578790829961
166;0;-82.4610489130326
167;0;-86.9831596869971
168;0;-82.1801287408513
169;0;-79.8171950283709
170;0;-78.4819360217846
171;0;-79.084855710995
172;0;-79.9327369247774
173;0;-86.8990923707102
174;0;-89.2225910962044
175;0;-83.8837549765372
176;0;-80.6717632389545
177;0;-80.9088196287483
178;0;-77.5713399675146
179;0;-82.5431029034273
180;0;-79.5893461697156
181;0;-82.6134438815028
182;0;-80.6353056739144
183;0;-85.3409857595349
184;0;-82.8939531336502
185;0;-76.6512970418582
186;0;-76.4591228937374
187;0;-77.2232510364499
188;0;-76.5274958458099
189;0;-72.5755098563323
190;0;-74.0371812249099
191;0;-73.2995352767215
192;0;-76.5479219677692
193;0;-31.5632330987417
194;0;-35.2564102564102
195;0;-28.687647184757
196;0;-28.9575289575289
197;0;-28.7986245433053
198;0;-28.6391042204995
199;0;-28.4789644012944
200;0;-28.966709900562
201;0;-28.5899935022742
202;0;-28.8628472222222
203;0;-28.4844531419873
204;0;-29.193899782135
205;0;-28.5963763370443
206;0;-28.8713910761154
207;0;-29.3666447512601
208;0;-28.32674571805
209;0;-28.8228822882288
210;0;-28.6596119929453
211;0;-29.1583830351225
212;0;-28.4373616644532
213;0;-28.6409915891987
214;0;-28.9642936349523
215;0;-29.2171213129297
216;0;-34.7656793213739
217;0;-35.8897243107769
218;0;-55.8347292015633
219;0;-58.0744472432129
220;0;-56.3973063973063
221;0;-57.6652601969057
222;0;-59.9266779469825
223;0;-59.7204574332909
224;0;-59.4002667353247
225;0;-58.2790901882854
226;0;-57.3180076628352
227;0;-56.6560987654321
228;-1.21871484147276;-56.1206756257865
229;-1.65367557662232;-56.1466167530928
230;-2.18816405543197;-59.0042118573952
231;-2.63555600689375;-55.1608085321462
232;-3.15517070958296;-58.9650224665896
233;-3.67261413123137;-55.6800120541222
234;-3.51615929066935;-55.9674325870131
235;-3.33808291420601;-55.3454808370968
236;-3.15596623494926;-56.1189291979122
237;-3.05747070708032;-55.2796929293025
238;-3.36452182637075;-55.8089662708151
239;-3.67243945897634;-55.5983653849022
240;-3.98135103134024;-58.2776473276365
241;-4.2914159340709;-54.9438375864925
242;-4.91848513142185;-55.894525904357
243;-5.55569860264527;-57.80299989307
244;-6.22839473119801;-64.9878058237285
245;-6.96333300691821;-65.0002514520274
246;-7.37663208514306;-65.2275994199634
247;-7.84295058037761;-65.77453375478
248;-8.38748653567279;-64.5407781115898
249;-9.04719546295989;-66.2691978367693
250;-6.98382937740502;-65.4563159239223
251;-5.23968086098197;-65.8937115922789
252;-3.5960512603585;-65.0700842517691
253;-2.22877445369613;-67.0151324507161
254;-1.82060162974159;-66.7209462327023
255;-1.41238235943444;-68.2953830423736
256;-1.00406335639015;-66.9465055866058
257;-0.595506353096537;-67.9090406866079
258;-0.448102197200428;-68.8803501395221
259;-0.298569919022679;-69.7693470157013
260;-0.149211767942852;-68.1925644890424
261;0;-72.647061821108
262;0;-74.1057769710913
263;0;-73.3198688597028
264;0;-71.8792248635036
265;0;-71.5888421941266
266;0;-80.3284499510636
267;0;-73.5477486316806
268;0;-73.2077362669015
269;0;-76.2611090523047
270;0;-73.809136928294
271;0;-76.2637273856678
272;0;-72.0023362528579
273;0;-73.7792678819013
274;0;-71.0723269509809
275;0;-76.2494351783692
276;0;-76.8273175857509
277;0;-79.2495604674465
278;0;-72.3663519368976
279;0;-74.4850440348868
280;0;-70.8169304129315
281;0;-72.0386452405222
282;0;-70.7274248598861
283;0;-68.0671253498969
284;0;-66.2722765765842
285;0;-65.2612447880968
286;0;-63.7845205133842
287;0;-64.4336700890955
288;0;-66.3446133788117
289;0;-30.1102629346904
290;0;-32.7172296579562
291;0;-30.0127713920817
292;0;-29.4305822136916
293;0;-29.9145299145299
294;0;-29.7580817812031
295;0;-30.03003003003
296;0;-29.2284547603696
297;0;-30.1464254952627
298;0;-29.3419633225458
299;0;-30.2637267617812
300;0;-29.6729478016027
301;0;-30.3819444444444
302;0;-30.223961730811
303;0;-29.4117647058823
304;0;-30.1244269810085
305;0;-29.7462817147856
306;0;-30.0241069471838
307;0;-29.6442687747035
308;0;-29.9229922992299
309;0;-29.7795414462081
310;0;-29.8210735586481
311;0;-29.4676386127678
312;0;-30.414052697616
313;0;-30.4271356783919
314;0;-46.6247379454926
315;0;-57.0267619447947
316;0;-59.6993959825818
317;0;-66.2447257383966
318;0;-67.8228990411731
319;0;-68.0502611887618
320;0;-68.6482661004953
321;0;-70.8708505367013
322;0;-67.1072830917445
323;0;-68.6419886586076
324;-0.709681060350361;-68.5888237005301
325;-0.897578362012933;-65.2760058464364
326;-1.18684306452105;-67.4352934905557
327;-1.48424679117049;-64.9151836680403
328;-1.78169108793586;-64.6321559271098
329;-2.07916661202743;-64.865519355631
330;-2.37665203489488;-64.4473545696434
331;-2.67411836614717;-65.168041288771
332;-2.97153089851594;-65.7888347807176
333;-3.3690459065225;-64.9881833108944
334;-3.99093394224187;-64.665386197981
335;-4.61541650218298;-64.818874219972
336;-5.24714599268052;-66.3264424708642
337;-5.90067045446377;-65.1087967542674
338;-5.67847828924815;-64.8922395915664
339;-5.46965694692162;-64.6743755107355
340;-5.26721391010479;-64.9076933644733
341;-5.06956039464059;-65.2903800119254
342;-4.67664217546059;-68.673286102505
343;-4.28601987504835;-66.4999342679424
344;-3.89732373991305;-66.268029562182
345;-3.51025843943871;-65.5731920948405
346;-3.20240131343221;-65.6115299388334
347;-2.89545093136158;-65.2401322834146
348;-2.52628261370875;-68.9064932341035
349;-2.22903093055711;-68.0087347768147
350;-1.85781128042186;-66.6981226601565
351;-1.48658604953854;-68.7216593627794
352;-1.11533543857283;-67.7440185026806
353;-0.743991611418294;-66.9354073562074
354;-0.557989699525375;-67.4647121679953
355;-0.373242601559311;-67.672837305083
356;-0.186514654376602;-72.2543410137858
357;0;-73.4050691311879
358;0;-74.5310432387154
359;0;-77.3255621555822
360;0;-71.9187874937959
361;0;-72.2499935602134
362;0;-74.5486550416795
363;0;-76.7638180076587
364;0;-74.8324526705189
365;0;-74.6227504485985
366;0;-74.0314734265626
367;0;-80.3236380890496
368;0;-71.6274794755364
369;0;-76.9871281339997
370;0;-76.9173347619452
371;0;-79.7918850256271
372;0;-79.3552239179693
373;0;-74.7750651830812
374;0;-71.2264547631816
375;0;-71.9716280434719
376;0;-72.6216401403657
377;0;-70.589752748757
378;0;-69.6864884896176
379;0;-69.1361092145706
380;0;-68.1555498425485
381;0;-68.0984376169382
382;0;-65.2046944308114
383;0;-66.6586117810107
384;0;-63.8252756573367
385;0;-30.2256279267773
386;0;-31.1367029217317
387;0;-30.7692307692307
388;0;-30.8285163776493
389;0;-30.5179454115624
390;0;-31.0077519379844
391;0;-30.6364617044228
392;0;-30.9122351923908
393;0;-30.5393112410656
394;0;-31.25
395;0;-30.6588388780169
396;0;-30.718954248366
397;0;-31.4341846758349
398;0;-30.6211723534558
399;0;-30.9007232084155
400;0;-30.5226174791392
401;0;-31.2431243124312
402;0;-30.6437389770723
403;0;-31.1464546056991
404;0;-30.4736609119079
405;0;-31.1288534043025
406;0;-30.6231980483477
407;0;-30.6858652552538
408;0;-55.3222222222222
409;0;-64.9244444444444
410;0;-64.9916666666666
411;0;-66.4821627033792
412;0;-66.9729880256196
413;0;-67.8391959798995
414;0;-69.4619147449336
415;0;-68.2359534818551
416;0;-70.8473625140291
417;0;-67.2875403848855
418;0;-67.278569186954
419;0;-66.3556050632911
420;-2.29859550588811;-66.6530258856349
421;-3.26917689852209;-64.872662737302
422;-1.73102179924716;-65.2386470715783
423;-2.09967431712483;-65.2064281297609
424;-2.40244719625789;-65.3087652790465
425;-2.65985221720818;-64.7644273806068
426;-2.91762174496329;-65.8239398277519
427;-3.37602702157435;-64.9782972682453
428;-33.0923113978477;-66.6925361485149
429;-35.4929770301321;-66.6125269598086
430;-35.5597986313499;-66.2409152100861
431;-35.7560607806911;-65.6016648800255
432;-36.1872973753816;-67.5220158595928
433;-36.7046029684427;-65.4915152566096
434;-35.9620423683405;-65.7323187125662
435;-35.3317194355713;-67.2332683547913
436;-34.8022812448409;-65.1061247845585
437;-34.3642368847408;-65.6697087454203
438;-31.7208786960583;-65.2097170113919
439;-28.8348533681036;-68.3903172179554
440;-25.8674279155892;-67.5098293846095
441;-22.895195787966;-66.0511067725395
442;-19.4613948662898;-65.7682591655083
443;-16.0974173299048;-66.2508443352452
444;-12.8701982525095;-66.3029416788189
445;-6.60459898639809;-66.910564423266
446;-5.70596903296237;-67.0629301235128
447;-4.68411142911856;-67.4676384196244
448;-3.56322402107813;-67.0730918136425
449;-2.36242291338818;-69.8027162983244
450;-1.77311593661724;-69.6089188910747
451;-1.19500430865261;-68.9745165514855
452;-0.596503921623393;-72.3115767077564
453;0;-70.8583329349175
454;0;-75.1636004688419
455;0;-81.1348698157333
456;0;-78.8371811724929
457;0;-74.3078870416596
458;0;-74.4315447430787
459;0;-77.0841955890598
460;0;-72.1202976888137
461;0;-79.4921416381636
462;0;-76.0835093629955
463;0;-76.4732750640914
464;0;-74.0772922540458
465;0;-75.4136057290219
466;0;-74.50943417528
467;0;-71.3912105436315
468;0;-80.8502597249159
469;0;-74.203888138832
470;0;-74.7441214010096
471;0;-71.4105087210656
472;0;-70.7143849874096
473;0;-70.2628940541495
474;0;-72.038929768257
475;0;-68.2571795828541
476;0;-68.8473166570209
477;0;-65.4647436551415
478;0;-66.2817451256751
479;0;-64.2606944408337
480;0;-63.3074935400516
481;0;-18.3744055339386
482;0;-17.1106779293913
483;0;-17.7604505089885
484;0;-17.3611111111111
485;0;-18.0121527777777
486;0;-17.3950858882365
487;0;-18.0827886710239
488;0;-17.4291938997821
489;0;-17.6817288801571
490;0;-17.6817288801571
491;0;-18.1539807524059
492;0;-17.9706333552487
493;0;-17.313171159325
494;0;-18.006148440931
495;0;-17.3473869126043
496;0;-17.8217821782178
497;0;-17.416225749559
498;0;-18.0776014109347
499;0;-17.4508504528385
500;0;-17.8926441351888
501;0;-17.4856131031429
502;0;-17.7422931913949
503;0;-17.5205145265025
504;0;-6.93999166169741
505;0;-9.54605638980865E-12
506;0;0
507;0;-1.40021762086285E-12
508;0;-4.14814814814588
509;0;-13.6213250287271
510;0;-58.6749712675663
511;0;-73.1762873985102
512;0;-79
513;0;-79.8219997218745
514;0;-81.1375993308239
515;0;-81.7978782802903
516;-3.32407980644207;-84.2465116722702
517;-4.62488988075124;-82.4306553439474
518;-1.55611434488775;-88.7075785455322
519;-1.86306144329846;-84.6352275487979
520;-2.28249354357221;-85.19495145603
521;-2.74137525284092;-83.3706771210808
522;-3.29365268720861;-82.4779002258865
523;-3.77367659955636;-82.8768914895733
524;-27.4490477871167;-83.2163780144215
525;-28.5634382723191;-83.8362683543094
526;-31.8123481486086;-83.116203023892
527;-34.4785276838281;-83.7823071666357
528;-37.2090384469913;-85.7845370224898
529;-39.9345546995859;-85.6946004596316
530;-38.258067804789;-86.1433724642871
531;-36.6882788577858;-83.6418277107186
532;-35.2357544799709;-83.8540793653403
533;-33.8565681744704;-83.4027211961992
534;-31.2598647383512;-83.2722882040791
535;-28.5120406025747;-82.4471882184656
536;-25.7277224413134;-81.8543663876599
537;-22.9625013251841;-81.5159060860875
538;-19.7540250973944;-83.0742216581881
539;-16.6137374466567;-81.3152615494298
540;-13.5875052617733;-81.1389627340024
541;-6.82454023268529;-80.613611960205
542;-5.85800810883523;-80.7092494143885
543;-4.6525443330415;-80.121960791911
544;-3.27047274288342;-82.8306228864597
545;-1.77863522250241;-84.2916817870495
546;-1.33411776607307;-82.2436452108
547;-0.896196414868283;-81.511853823559
548;-0.447556142149861;-81.755264047503
549;0;-83.243000786623
550;0;-84.1704432573882
551;0;-86.9635804158772
552;0;-85.2116656654791
553;0;-86.0819744937302
554;0;-85.1582482376912
555;0;-90.1271053175926
556;0;-93.7234904621546
557;0;-97.4689027199559
558;0;-92.3158840472653
559;0;-88.6642213757026
560;0;-89.8194525673533
561;0;-86.3073876495113
562;0;-94.5391885174295
563;0;-85.8790316434559
564;0;-96.2162340426631
565;0;-90.2787392893043
566;0;-88.720850859544
567;0;-85.7807844201855
568;0;-86.8733475565804
569;0;-84.4505262576704
570;0;-83.5777311489473
571;0;-83.3335435464992
572;0;-83.6931951857303
573;0;-80.6893755404381
574;0;-78.4295502589973
575;0;-77.005577005577
576;0;-77.8856526429341
577;0;-15.5945419103313
578;0;-15.8420138888888
579;0;-15.6555772994129
580;0;-16.3078930202217
581;0;-15.4684095860566
582;0;-15.9041394335512
583;0;-15.4987993887797
584;0;-16.3719711853307
585;0;-15.7480314960629
586;0;-16.185476815398
587;0;-15.9982467674775
588;0;-15.5599386368617
589;0;-16.2494510320597
590;0;-15.371102327624
591;0;-16.061606160616
592;0;-15.6215621562156
593;0;-16.3139329805996
594;0;-15.2418820410868
595;0;-16.1254694057875
596;0;-15.9362549800796
597;0;-15.9362549800796
598;0;-15.3027278775781
599;0;-16.1898425371479
600;0;-6.82924181307052
601;0;0
602;0;-5.92592592592895
603;0;-8.88888888887656
604;0;-8.88888888889751
605;0;-10.0963185407542
606;0;-48.322139512445
607;0;-77.3
608;0;-75.694618272841
609;0;-75.187969924812
610;0;-77.2340722152516
611;-1.50167002604896;-77.9952490321907
612;-2.25549878562302;-77.6823109882538
613;-3.23796469749133;-77.6389735247296
614;-3.07564329818647;-80.3764289323054
615;-4.01237465899527;-78.0396256773967
616;-4.84273900361632;-78.5417544747836
617;-5.60909710287335;-80.764201445795
618;-6.30479170360821;-78.8729125563542
619;-6.75917605301768;-78.1473581282227
620;-18.6043580640722;-79.0431407958485
621;-21.5853398847839;-78.7727955396725
622;-23.0991393547731;-79.1526320279841
623;-24.7792988660997;-82.4030329981778
624;-26.5663943240454;-79.4764472340983
625;-28.4199939246734;-79.6027896235981
626;-26.6268438986575;-78.4652800061751
627;-24.9751138737774;-79.1987923327339
628;-23.4500362656254;-82.2126293562988
629;-22.0531366780998;-79.1419968282986
630;-20.2186815167757;-79.8957540255755
631;-18.5114318773483;-78.0570434754274
632;-16.9268922168166;-77.4572790914938
633;-15.4571835717612;-77.1876950106416
634;-12.3852598635315;-76.759933320974
635;-9.63336690745753;-76.3649165794694
636;-7.24333064878226;-78.2649433874663
637;-4.85526402471194;-76.5437370891093
638;-4.02466183821563;-78.0031057022754
639;-3.18269052348985;-81.4317715555329
640;-2.33416341761529;-78.805455590756
641;-1.48427809005252;-83.5632095177615
642;-1.11334298608744;-79.6202814082177
643;-0.746799768678218;-81.2297124310793
644;-0.373035366982487;-77.4251131394177
645;0;-78.9970856910858
646;0;-80.0778760053185
647;0;-87.5872754084257
648;0;-89.0454243218131
649;0;-83.2260866272233
650;0;-82.4793484971309
651;0;-82.2027395075815
652;0;-83.3401442619711
653;0;-83.7812397800094
654;0;-90.0669123603769
655;0;-83.0463873089934
656;0;-83.7963157356559
657;0;-84.4305722780573
658;0;-89.3133164251607
659;0;-86.5247404730709
660;0;-84.1734852570746
661;0;-87.9763227780769
662;0;-80.8582489114876
663;0;-81.3232700865805
664;0;-80.8327995536607
665;0;-80.6148544640548
666;0;-79.4512164580133
667;0;-80.0121163900645
668;0;-78.5853957996049
669;0;-76.5047218029927
670;0;-74.2253196585484
671;0;-77.2277227722772
672;0;-76.3612217795484
```

Please let me know where you think there is a mistake.
Thanks.

Comment: I guess you should load the `fillbetween` library, strip off all unrelated packages (`\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}`, really?), and tell us which fills you want to achieve.

Comment: And if you want to speed up the answer even more, add the `\documentclass` and load the data via filecontents.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marmot has already pointed out in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449591/95441) the problem is that just the first and the last given coordinate in a path are "connected" and the area in-between is filled. To overcome this issue you can simply add a trailing path before the `;` to "better" connect the first with the last coordinate. In this case PGFPlots already provides the `\closedcycle` command which is most likely exactly what you are looking for. Thus, usage of the `fillbetween` library is not needed.

I think you want to fill the area between the data points and y=0, which results in a bit different graph than provided by Marmot. In case you want to fill the "lower" part I present a possible solution as well in commented form.

(Please note that I have removed all unnecessary stuff that is not related to the question, so it is easier to identify the real solution to the problem.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
% (The data file `Collective_El_productionOC_weekB.csv' can be found at
%  <https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449571/95441>)
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        enlarge x limits=-1,
        height=4cm,
        width=10cm,
        ymin=-100,
        ymax=0,
        xtick={1, 96, 192, 288, 384, 480, 576},
        xticklabels={30/07, 31/07, 01/08, 02/08, 03/08, 04/08, 05/08},
        grid=major,
        xlabel={Time [days]},
        ylabel={Power [kW]},
        table/col sep=semicolon,
    ]
        % assuming you want to fill between zero and the values
        \addplot [draw=none,fill=red]  table [y=chp_OC] {Collective_El_productionOC_weekB.csv}
            \closedcycle
        ;
        \addplot [draw=none,fill=blue] table [y=pv_OC]  {Collective_El_productionOC_weekB.csv}
            \closedcycle
        ;

        % assuming you want to fill between `ymin' and the values
        % (please note that then you have to change the order of the plots)
%        \addplot [draw=none,fill=blue] table [y=pv_OC] {Collective_El_productionOC_weekB.csv}
%            |- (rel axis cs:0,0)
%        ;
%        \addplot [draw=none,fill=red]  table [y=chp_OC]{Collective_El_productionOC_weekB.csv}
%            |- (rel axis cs:0,0)
%        ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, you may have to load the `fillbetween` library. Why? Why does your approach not work? Well, if you just add `fill`, Ti*k*Z will fill a closed path. The plot is not a closed path, so Ti*k*Z just closes it by connecting the last and first points. Apparently, that's not what you want. Presumably you want to fill the region between the plot and an axis. Unfortunately, you were not too specific, so I just guessed an axis, but this can also be changed (and made more elegant as well). So here we go, then.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Dark2}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={font={\scriptsize}}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.03)},anchor=south}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
font={\scriptsize}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlarge x limits=-1,
    height=4cm,
    width=\textwidth,
    axis y line=left,
    axis line style=-,
    y axis line style=-,
    %ymin=-30,
    ytick scale label code/.code={}, 
    xtick={1, 96, 192, 288, 384, 480, 576},
    xticklabels={30/07, 31/07, 01/08, 02/08, 03/08, 04/08, 05/08},
    grid=major,
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize},  
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
    label style={font=\scriptsize},
    title style={font=\scriptsize},
    xlabel={Time [days]},
    ylabel={Power [kW]},
    legend columns = 2,
    legend style={draw=none, fill=none}
    ]
\addplot[color=red,no marks,name path=red] table[col sep=semicolon,trim cells=true, y=chp_OC]{data/Collective_El_productionOC_weekB.csv};
\addlegendentry{CHP\textsubscript{OC}}
\addplot[color=blue,no marks=,name path=blue] table[col sep=semicolon,trim cells=true, y=pv_OC] {data/Collective_El_productionOC_weekB.csv};
\addlegendentry{PV\textsubscript{OC}}
\addplot[draw=none,name path=bottom] coordinates {(0,-100) (672,-100)};
\addplot [blue] fill between [of=bottom and blue];
\addplot [red] fill between [of=bottom and red];   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And even though I expect you not to like this, I cannot refrain from making some comments. This site is meant to help a lot of users by having clear questions and well-written answers. I think it is fair to say that people won't benefit from a question in which an excessive amount of irrelevant packages is loaded, an incredibly large amount of data is uploaded and the question is not very clear (at least to me it is not). You may also want to learn from other questions and answers, so could you perhaps consider playing by the rules and design your posts in such a way that others can also benefit from them?

Comment: Dear marmot,  you are right, I know my question was not very well formulated and I was providing way more packages and data than needed. I have the deadline for my thesis in 10 days and I didn't have much time to make the question nice or to do some serious research on the topic before posting my question, sorry for that.
I would like to thank you anyway for your answer, the graph is not what I wanted to achieve but I could get something with the fillbetween.